# Are silent remote push notifications deprecated in iOS 11?

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, unusernotificationcenter, cksubscription, silent-notification

Currently I'm able to receive silent push using app delegate's `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method.

That method is deprecated and [according to this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623117-application?language=objc) we're supposed to be switching to `UNUserNotificationCenter`'s `willPresent` method, but I can't seem to get it to work for silent push. Since there's no notification to present in a silent push, it would be counterintuitive if that did work, to say the least.

Have read [registering for push Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956482/registering-for-push-notifications-in-xcode-8-swift-3-0), [CKSub w/out notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934370/cloudkit-cksubscription-without-notifications), and plenty others but everything keeps coming back to the deprecated method.

**Is there an alternative we're supposed to be using for silent push** (which is not a user facing notification, but in this case it's a `CKQuerySubscription` report that triggers background activity)? **Or should `willPresent` work** for silent pushes (in which case I've missed a part of the config...)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler
```

or for Swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

}
```

The deprecated one is

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I don't know why the documentation doesn't redirect to that one.

Comment: Yeah that's weird. The deprecation info in UIApplication.h shows it though.